# blowup in finite time of $\frac{dx}{dt}=1+x^{10}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I feel like this is extremely silly question. It is a question from Strogatz' Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos
I want to show that $\frac{dx}{dt}=1+x^{10}$ blows up in finite based on the fact that  $\frac{dx}{dt}=1+x^2$ blows up in finite time.

Well clearly, $1+x^2 < 1+x^{10}$ but then I realized that this is only true for $x > 1$ (in absolute value)

So what if $x<1$?
Is there a nice and elegant way to do this problem without explicitly solving for a solution?

Comment: [ -1, 1] is a finite domain. Is there any reason why showing the result outside the domain is not sufficient?

Comment: It’s probably not in the spirit of the question, but I’d separate variables and integrate $x$ to infinity: Time it takes to blow up from $x=a$ is given by $\int_a^\infty dx/(1+x^{10})$, which converges since $\int_a^\infty dx/(1+x^2) < \pi$.

Comment: why is the time given by that expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate that $x$ gets to say $1.1$ in finite time--because $dx/dt \ge 1$ for all $x$, and then go from there.

Comment: Spot on.  You have recognized two regions of the solution and have an appropriate lower bound for each.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that

Answer (score 2):

I am working on Strogatz as well and stumbled upon this question. I fleshed out the solution proposed by Michael E2 in the second comment on the question, figuring someone following in my footsteps would be curious to see it:

Let $f(t)$ be the solution to the differential equation $\dot{x}=1+x^{10}$. Because $1+x^{10} > 0$ for all $x$, we know that $f'(t)$ is strictly positive and $f(t)$ is strictly monotone increasing and therefore invertible. Thus, we can calculate the time to reach infinity given we start at a value $x=a$ as follows:

$$ f^{-1}(\infty)-f^{-1}(a) = f^{-1}(x)\Big|_a^\infty $$

Now, because $f$ is the solution to a differential equation, we know that it is differentiable on the relevant domain and the above discussion implies that it is never zero. Therefore, we can use the well known result about derivatives of inverse functions to observe that:

\begin{align*}
    f^{-1}(x)\Big|_a^\infty &= \int_a^\infty \left( f^{-1}(x)\right)' \ dx\\
    &= \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))} \ dx \\
    &= \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{1+f(f^{-1}(x))^{10}} \ dx \tag{ \(f'(t)=1+f(t)^{10}\)  }\\
    &= \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^{10}} \ dx \\
\end{align*}

Let $a \geq 1$ then we have:

$$\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^{10}} \leq \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}< \infty $$

Comment: I like it. Nice job Ben

Answer (score 0):

I am also working with Strogatz and managed to reach this solution:

Recall from page 25 of the course text: *"[The] reciprocal $\frac{1}{|f'(x^*)|}$ is a $\mathbf {characteristic}$ $\mathbf {time}$ $\mathbf {scale}$: it determines the time required for x(t) to vary significantly in the neighborhood of $x^*$."* (see Ben's post for proof). In this case, we let f(x) := "the ODE in question".

In other terms, the characteristic time scale provides us with the equation which tells us the instantaneous rate of change in time to travel each position increment at any given position (i.e., the derivative of total time $\mathit T$ with respect to position; $\frac{dT}{dx}$). It should now make sense how we could find the total time needed for a solution curve to travel from position x = $\mathit a$ to x = $\mathit b$: i.e., we take the integral $\int_a^b \frac{dx}{|f'(x)|}$.

Using this fact, we can calculate the following: (time needed for a solution curve to travel from any real finite position $\mathit a$ $\ge$ 1 to b $\to$ $\infty$) = $\int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{\frac{d}{dx}({1+x^{10})}}$.

Noting that $\forall x \ge 1, \frac{d}{dx}(1+x^{2})\le\frac{d}{dx}(1+x^{10})$, and also that (assumed) $1+x^{2}$ blows up in finite time, we deduce then that $\int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{\frac{d}{dx}({1+x^{10})}} \le \int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{\frac{d}{dx}({1+x^{2})}} \lt \infty$; hence, $\frac{d}{dx}(1+x^{10}$) necessarily must blow up in finite time.

---

Note #1: this is my first post on this site. Apologies if any notation seems off...still getting accustomed to everything. I have only used the site answers for the longest time; thought I'd try to contribute something. :)

Note #2: my response was heavily inspired by Ben's. I do believe an error may have occurred when he was calculating the derivative of $1+x^{10}$ (four lines from the bottom).